# Identifying and sharpening carbide tipped planer blade

Tags: sharpening

Below are photos of an electric (hand) planer blade that came with a used Makita power planer, model 1900B.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I believe the blades are carbide tipped, but am not certain. I could not search the model number and find anything conclusive, perhaps because these blades are old.

Are the blades carbide tipped? If so, can they be sharpened at home, or best sent to a professional?

Comment: Good, helpful pictures - thank you!

Comment: Planar blades are some of the most high precision blades you can get.  Sharpening is best left to an expert with the proper equipment.

Answer (score 1):

The blades certainly have some sort of inset visible at the edge, which might well be carbide.

Home sharpening of carbide is possible with diamond abrasives.

But, if you have to ask, it's likely that a better job will be done by a competent shop, since you inquire about "best."